# Proportionality constant in Montgomery-Vaughan Theorem 7.20

Tags: nt.number-theory, divisors-multiples

In *Multiplicative Number Theory - Vol. I* by Montgomery and Vaughan the following result is proved.

**Theorem 7.20** Let $A(x,r)$ denote the number of $n\leq x$ such that $\Omega(n)\leq r \log \log x,$ and let $B(x,r)$ denote the number of $n\leq x$ for which $\Omega(n)\geq r \log \log x.$ If $0<r\leq 1$ and $x\geq 2$ then
$$
A(x,r)\ll x(\log x)^{r-1-r \log r}.
$$
If $1\leq r \leq R<2$ and $x\geq 2$ then
$$
B(x,r)\ll_{R} x(\log x)^{r-1-r \log r}.
$$
How does the $R$-dependent proportionality constant vary as $R$ ranges over $[1,2)$?

Also, the indicated proof techniques are the same for both $A(x,r)$ and $B(x,r),$ but $r<R$ is required for $B(x,r)$. What happens if $r\geq 2$? Surely then even fewer $n$ satisfy the inequality $\Omega(n)\geq r \log \log n$ so the bound on $B(x,r)$ still holds. So why the restriction $r<R$?

Comment: Certainly $B(x,r)$ is a decreasing function of $r$, but that doesn't imply that the bound on $B(x,r)$ continues to hold for $r\ge2$. The reason that $R<2$ is required in the given proof is that it proceeds via upper bounds for $\sum_{n\le x} r^{\Omega(n)}$; this sum genuinely changes character when $r>2$, since the integers $n$ that are powers of $2$ (or nearly so) are then increased by the map $n\mapsto r^{\Omega(n)}$; for example, the largest power of $2$ less than $x$ already gives a contribution of $x^{(\log r)/\log 2}$ to the sum.

Comment: @GregMartin, I will accept that as an answer if you would like to enter it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** *My only goal is to mark this as answered.*

As explained by Greg Martin in a comment:

Certainly $(,)$
is a decreasing function of $$,
but that doesn't imply that the bound on $(,)$
continues to hold for $\geq 2$.

The reason that $<2$
is required in the given proof is that it proceeds via upper bounds for
$$
\sum_{n \leq x} \Omega(n),
$$
and this sum genuinely changes character when $>2$, since the integers $$
that are powers of 2 (or nearly so) are then increased by the map $n \mapsto \Omega(n)$
; for example, the largest power of $2$ less than $$ already gives a contribution of

$$x^{(\log r)/\log 2}$$
to the sum.